# Is there a way to kill keep-alive connection before keep-alive-timeout?

Tags: multithreading, http, go, connection, keep-alive

I am creating connections to server inside go routines. They use a keep-alive persistent connection.
We are using keep-alive-timeout to kill the connection.

The application I have to build needs to be highly performant. Thus we wish to kill some "threads" on the fly. However, from out knowledge go routines cannot be killed like we do in Java. Thus we are looking into destroying the persistent connection at will.

Thus, is there any way we can forcefully break out of a persistent connection even before keep-alive timeout ?

Comment: When you say "break out of a persistent connection", do you mean "return from `Read` on a TCP connection"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: Close the connection.